# Create a SNMP event at startup on Linux

Tags: linux, snmp

I want to trigger an SNMP event when our machine has booted up and I would like to have the info if the shutdown was properly done or it was because of a fatal error. And suggestion which path to go with?

OS is Oracle Enterprise Linux,

```
Linux version 2.6.32-300.32.2.el5uek (mockbuild@ca-build56.us.oracle.com) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)) #1 SMP Tue Aug
28 10:15:29 EDT 2012
```

Comment: Why dont you use a syslog server for it? `snmptrap` is use for sending snmp traps. In the case of kernel panic of network problem you are not be able to recieve traps. Using ping hearbeat catch those situations. I recommend nagios or zabbix as a monitoring software.

Answer (score 1):

[I'm not entirely sure you understand how SNMP works.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol#Overview_and_basic_concepts)

An SNMP server simply provides clients that request data with information when they request it, similar to a web server but over UDP instead of TCP.

You can configure an SNMP daemon to send out what is known as an [**SNMP Trap**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol#Trap), however - perhaps this is closer to what you want.

In this scenario, the snmpd server plays the role of receiver, not requestor.
The server in question (the one that reboots) should still send out an SNMP trap itself; if it is running an SNMP agent it will most likely send out the **coldstart** trap signal when it performs a cold boot.